# reference file path from text box vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to reference the file path of an excel book that is in a text box in my code.

Below is what I tried but I get an error saying

> "subscript out of range".

The problem I'm having is with lines such as `Workbooks.Open (txtOutput.text)`

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click() 
 Dim countx As Integer 
countx = Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets.Count
Workbooks.Open (txtOutput.Text) 
For I = 1 To countx

Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets(I).range(txtRange.Text).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets(I).Paste
Destination = Workbooks(txtOutput.Text).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(30 * I + 1, "A") 
Next I 
Workbooks(txtOutput.Text).Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Select Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.4, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft 
End Sub
```

Comment: It's just that `txtOutput.text` is not a path to a file, add just before `MsgBox txtOutput.text` to check it's value! ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying but I don't think I understood you. I added `MsgBox txtOutput.text` after `Dim countx as Integer` and the file path popped up. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Did the file path *only* display? Or did the file path **and** file name pop-up? The `Workbooks` object needs both the path and name to open, and at least the name to reference other objects within it once its opened (i.e. `Worksheets`)

Comment: I get the same error for every line that has something similar; such as `countx = Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets.Count`. `Call` won't work for something like this

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The entire path showed up. Like C:\\Users\.....\filename.xlsx is what appears

Comment: This may seem stupid, but try passing the textbox text into a string variable and then using that variable to reference in the `Workbook` methods.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I still get the same error

Comment: is there a workbook with the name in that location? Does the path even exist as written? Also remove the `()` from the 'Workbook.Open` line. They are only needed when you are setting the `Workbook.Open` to a variable.

Comment: Both workbooks exist in the path. When I reference the files directly in my code (running off a macro directly in the file rather than a userform) everything works perfectly.

Comment: Did you take the parenthesis out of the `Workbooks.Open` line (not sure if you saw my last comment, but I edited it to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah I made that change, thanks. That line is fine but the line that gets an error is

`countx = Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets.Count`

Comment: is the workbook `txtFilePath.Text` open? If not, you need to open it. If it is open, is the `txtFilePath.Text` the full path? Or just the workbook name? If it's the full path, manipulate the string to just get the workbook name and see if that works. It should.

Comment: Yeah that seems to have worked. Just having some issues with the picture not pasting to the book. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is because you are trying to use an object that does not exits.

Also if you are not setting a workbook to a variable you do not need to add "()"

So the line

```
Workbooks.Open (txtOutput.Text)
```

Should be

```
Workbooks.Open txtOutput.Text
```

I cleaned your code a little bit

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()

    Dim countx As Integer
    Dim wbOpened As Workbook
    Dim strFilePath As String

    'Initialize the variables
    countx = Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets.Count
    strFilePath = txtOutput.Text

    ' Make sure that the file exits
    If DoesFileExist(strFilePath) Then
        ' Open the workbook and assign it to the variable
        Set wbOpened = Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)

        For I = 1 To countx
            Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets(I).Range(txtRange.Text).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
            Workbooks(txtFilePath.Text).Worksheets(I).Paste
            Destination = wbOpened.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(30 * I + 1, "A")
        Next I

        wbOpened.Worksheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.4, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    Else
        MsgBox "The file""" & strFilePath & """ could not be found"
    End If

End Sub

'Function to check if the file exists.
Private Function DoesFileExist(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
    DoesFileExist = (Dir$(strPath, vbNormal) <> vbNullString)
End Function
```

I hope this helps :)
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not having problems with the files existing. I have already confirmed that the paths are copying over correctly. Thanks again though!!

Comment: H i Mahir, Look at my comment about : Workbooks.Open (txtOutput.Text)

Comment: Yeah I saw that, the change was suggested to me by another person. Thanks though!